# ArrayBlockingQueue not supported on Google Web Toolkit

Tags: gwt, blockingqueue

Hello I am creating a game with libgdx, but when I want to compile it to gwt 2.8.2, I got the following error : `[ERROR] Line 98: No source code is available for type java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue<E>; did you forget to inherit a required module? [ERROR] Line 81: No source code is available for type java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue<E>; did you forget to inherit a required module?`

After further investigation, it seems that BlockingQueue is not supported by GWT (source : http://www.howsoftworks.net/guavgwt/Queues)

What is the supported equivalent ?

Thank you

Comment: The model of JavaScript is single-threaded. Which means if there were any blocking operation, then entire JavaScript engine in your GWT app would be blocked. This does not make much sense. What actually are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is a client sever application and my server sending me Json packets. The client has got main libgdx rendering thread and also a network reader and writer thread. You have the possibility to execute instruction in the render thread by using postRunnable function that send instructions  from a thead  to the main rendering thread. So In my reading thread I wanted to simply store incoming packet and in my render thread process them one by one by getting each element of this blocking queue . At this moment I use a simple qeue from ligdx but its not thread safe. ...

Comment: I guess the only way would be that you implement your own blocking and rethink what you are doing in an asynchronous way.